# Javascript: flatten multidimensional array into array of unique paths

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree

Im trying to build a list of all the unique paths down a tree / 
multidimensional array of objects.

Assuming this data...

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    items: [
      {
        id: '1.1',
        items: [ { id: '1.1.1' }, { id: '1.1.2' }, { id: '1.1.3' }, ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    items: [
      {
        id: '2.1',
        items: [ { id: '2.1.1' }, { id: '2.1.2' }, { id: '2.1.3' },  ]
      },
      {
        id: '2.2',
        items: [ { id: '2.2.1' } ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to end up with an array structure like this..

```
const result = [
  ['1', '1.1', '1.1.1'],
  ['1', '1.1', '1.1.2'],
  ['1', '1.1', '1.1.3'],
  ['2', '2.1', '2.1.1'],
  ['2', '2.1', '2.1.2'],
  ['2', '2.1', '2.1.3'],
  ['2', '2.2', '2.2.1']
];
```

Where each entry is an array of a unique `path` down the original tree structure.

I'm having real trouble getting each path as a separate entry.  What I have so far returns them the path down to the lower level and appends the bottom level ids to the current path.

```
function flatten(items, path = []) {
  let result = [];
  items.forEach( item => {
    path.push(item.id);
    if (item.items && item.items.length) {  
      result.push(flatten(item.items, path.slice(0) )); //slice to clone the array
    }
    else {
      result.push(...path);
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Here is a JS fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/9ptdm1ve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method to create recursive function and return array as a result. You can use `concat()` method to create copy of `prev` array so that on each level of recursion you have new copy, because arrays are passed by reference and otherwise you would be changing original array.

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","items":[{"id":"1.1","items":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]}]},{"id":"2","items":[{"id":"2.1","items":[{"id":"2.1.1"},{"id":"2.1.2"},{"id":"2.1.3"}]},{"id":"2.2","items":[{"id":"2.2.1"}]}]}]

function build(data, prev = []) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    const copy = prev.concat(e.id)
    if (e.items) r = r.concat(build(e.items, copy))
    else r.push(copy)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = build(data);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated path in the foreach callback is shared. It should be local.

```
function flatten(items, path = []) {
  let result = [];
  items.forEach(item => {
    let localPath = path.slice(0);
    localPath.push(item.id);
    if (item.items && item.items.length) {  
      result.push(flatten(item.items, localPath));
    } else {
      result.push(localPath);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner method that will push all complete paths to the same result array:

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","items":[{"id":"1.1","items":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]}]},{"id":"2","items":[{"id":"2.1","items":[{"id":"2.1.1"},{"id":"2.1.2"},{"id":"2.1.3"}]},{"id":"2.2","items":[{"id":"2.2.1"}]}]}]

function flatten(items) {
  const result = [];

  const iterateItems = (items, path = []) =>
    items.forEach(({ id, items }) => {
      const localPath = [...path, id];

      if (items)
        iterateItems(items, localPath);
      else
        result.push(localPath);
    });

  iterateItems(items);

  return result;
}

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Another option is to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and flatten the results of each stage by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","items":[{"id":"1.1","items":[{"id":"1.1.1"},{"id":"1.1.2"},{"id":"1.1.3"}]}]},{"id":"2","items":[{"id":"2.1","items":[{"id":"2.1.1"},{"id":"2.1.2"},{"id":"2.1.3"}]},{"id":"2.2","items":[{"id":"2.2.1"}]}]}];

const flatten = (arr, path = []) => 
  [].concat(...arr.map(({ id, items }) => items ? 
    flatten(items, [...path, id]) : [[...path, id]]
  ));
  

const result = flatten(data);

console.log(result);
```